# Why did you close my question? the link does not answer it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen

[Could the particles of the standard model be states of a smaller set of particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731663/)

Answer (score 2):

The linked questions asks:

> What paper(s) or theory(s) describe or prove that the elementary particles that we have determined today cannot be made up of smaller more fundamental particles?

so it specifically includes theoretical evidence as well as experimental evidence.

Comment: if you read the answers given you would realize they do not discuss that

Comment: It's the question that's the duplicate not the answers.

Comment: My question is more specific, but I see, you guys just like to play cops.

Comment: @CarlosGauss I see you've edited the question to say you're specifically interested in group theory reasons. That seems different enough from the original question to be useful so I've voted to reopen it. Note however that [such theories do exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon) so the answer to our question is "yes".

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. You can close the question if you want.